# The lib and classes folders are staged and deployed with IntelliJ but gcloud command does not include them

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform, java-8

I have a Java 8 Spring Boot GAE Standard App and I use IntelliJ IDE (Cloud Code plugins for GAE applications).

I use AppEngine-web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <application>***</application>
    <service>***</service>
    <version>***</version>
    <url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>

    <system-properties>
      <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>

    <async-session-persistence enabled="true" />
    <instance-class>F2</instance-class>

    <resource-files>
        <include path="/**.json" />
    </resource-files>

    <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
    <env-variables>
        <env-var name="GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
                 value="WEB-INF/***.json" />
    </env-variables>
</appengine-web-app>
```

When I deploy my GAE app using IntelliJ, these folders are generated in my staging, and everything works well;

[image]

Here is a snapshot of my Run Configuration on IntelliJ
[image]

The issue arises when I deploy it using gcloud command:

```
gcloud app deploy src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml --version=something --promote --stop-previous-version --verbosity=debug
```

Here is the generated staging folder:

[image]

I have `.gitignore` file in my app root; I removed that to check if it is creating the issue and no luck and I also did the same with `.cloudignore`.

gcloud deploy skips files and the output is like:

```
DEBUG: Loading runtimes experiment config from [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml]
INFO: Reading [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x0000000006BB8988>]
DEBUG:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\runtime_builders.py", line 269, in _Read
    with contextlib.closing(storage_client.ReadObject(object_)) as f:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\storage\storage_api.py", line 317, in ReadObject
    object_=object_ref, err=http_exc.HttpException(err)))
BadFileException: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x0000000006BB8988>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
DEBUG: Experiment config file could not be read. This error is informational, and does not cause a deployment to fail. Reason: Unable to read the runtimes experiment config: [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml], error: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x0000000006BB8988>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\app\deploy.py", line 146, in _ServerSideExperimentEnabled
    runtimes_builder_root)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\runtime_builders.py", line 524, in LoadFromURI
    .format(uri, e))
ExperimentsError: Unable to read the runtimes experiment config: [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml], error: Could not read [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x0000000006BB8988>]. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object: runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
WARNING: <application> and <version> elements in `appengine-web.xml` are not respected
INFO: Executing staging command: [C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe -classpath C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg --enable_new_staging_defaults stage E:***\src\main\webapp c:\users\***\appdata\local\temp\tmp1nhtxn\tmpoizcfc]


DEBUG: Executing command: [u'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java.exe', u'-classpath', u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\platform\\google_appengine\\google\\appengine\\tools\\java\\lib\\appengine-tools-api.jar', u'com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg', u'--enable_new_staging_defaults', u'stage', u'E:***\\src\\main\\webapp', 'c:\\users\\***\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmp1nhtxn\\tmpoizcfc']
INFO: ------------------------------------ STDOUT ------------------------------------
Reading application configuration data...


Beginning interaction for module ***...
0% Scanning for jsp files.
2021-12-22 15:11:47.738:INFO::main: Logging initialized @167ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2021-12-22 15:11:48.115:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=0ms
0% Generated git repository information file.
Success.
Temporary staging for module *** directory left in C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1nhtxn\tmpoizcfc
------------------------------------ STDERR ------------------------------------
2021-12-22 15:11:47.221:INFO::main: Logging initialized @725ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to replicate this similar issue on a same project. This is because Java 8 may be considered a legacy version, but best practice still applies and that is to use App Engine Maven Plugin when submitting deployments. Full documentation could be found through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/uploadinganapp#using_maven_recommended).

I've changed the gcloud command:

```
gcloud app deploy src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml 
--version=something --promote --stop-previous-version --verbosity=debug
```

To this:

```
mvn clean package appengine:deploy
```

This process would take some time as it would clean and reinstall packages before deploying your project.

Here's a [Github link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine-java8/requests) similar to your project that you can try on your end as this one works for me.

**EDIT:**

Google App Maven plugin for Java 8 is still updated regularly based on this [Github link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin).

The standalone App Engine SDK, and the Maven plugin (`com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin`) which is based on it, are now shut down. You must use Cloud SDK tooling and migrate to the Cloud SDK-based Maven plugin (`com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin`). Full description and steps could be found through this [link on how to use Maven](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-maven).

That is why it is very important that we use `mvn clean package appengine:deploy`.

I would also include a code snippet from `pom.xml` containing the configurations that you need to set:

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
          <version>GCLOUD_CONFIG</version>
          <deploy.promote>true</deploy.promote>
          <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Full documentation can be found through this [link containing sample Java codes for handling requests](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/f12235bdfe1d4baa47fb72f470660ae04742b2f7/appengine-java8/requests)
Also, Intellij is also using a plugin for Google Cloud called Cloud Code, which is a similar plugin with Maven.

I've tried deploying an `app.yaml` file and got this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT:
WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml is required for this runtime.
```

Overall, it's not possible to use gcloud tool if you want to deploy a Java 8 project. If you really want to use gcloud, you need to upgrade to Java 11.

Here are the additional references that I've used to replicate this project:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref

Comment: I have not yet tried your solution, but some potential concerns:
How do you manage to do these parts `--version=something --promote --stop-previous-version --verbosity=debug` with `mvn clean package appengine:deploy`.
I am using bitbucket CICD and they use **gcloud**; so essentially ``mvn clean package appengine:deploy`` would not be a good approach. 

According to [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven) this tool is shut down

Comment: If the issue is **gcloud**, how does IntelliJ manage to deploy it as expected?

Comment: In addition, `stopPreviousVersion` only works for instances that are either on manual or basic scaling. See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--stop-previous-version

Comment: Great addition. I do not have the plugin in snippet you mentioned in my `pom` file. It seems Intellij cretaes an `Google App Engine Deployment.run.xml` file which contains all the deployment configurations such `--promote` and others. So I am not sure if they (Cloud Code) are essentially using only a Maven solution. I am going to give a try to your suggestions, but still the CICD issue remains as Bitbucket uses gcloud. I am discussing with them if they can support java8 using mvn approach.

Comment: I ran it using your solution and I got this error:
`opencv-3.4.2-0.jar], which has size [105650073] (greater than maximum allowed size of [33554432]). Please delete the file or add to the skip_files entry in your application .yaml file and try again.`

This issue does not arise when I use the Intellij Cloud Code approach. I use OpenCV and skipping that will break the application.

Comment: update: that is very interesting `cloud code` automatically splits the big jar files. For example for the opencv; it did it into `opencv-3.4.2-0-0001.jar`, `opencv-3.4.2-0-0002.jar` and `opencv-3.4.2-0-0003.jar` where each of them is less than 35 MB in size.

Added this to POM and it it is resolved
`<stage.enableJarSplitting>true</stage.enableJarSplitting>`